# Get html input values in server side in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" runat="Server">  
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
                    $("#slider-range").slider({
                        range: true,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                        values: [0, 75],
                        slide: function (event, ui) {
                            $("#value").val("" + ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
                        }
                    });
                    $("#value").val("" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
                    " - " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
                });
      </script>
    </asp:content>
```

I am using this code for a slider in my asp.net page. Now the value in displayed in the Html input.

```
      <input type="text" id="value" style="border: 0; font-weight: bold;" />
```

it is displayed as 0-75. How can I get both the values (0,75) separately in my server side so that i can write the values in database.

How to change the code so that in my server side I can asign values to 2 variables. The slider contains min value(0) and max value(75)[selected by users].

var a= 0;
var b= 75;

Comment: Have you tried to add runat="server" attribute and access the control by its ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do something like:

```
string[] vals = Request.Form["value"].Split('-');
int a = int.Parse(vals[0]);
int b = int.Parse(vals[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ASP.NET WebForms,not MVC, i strongly recommend that you stick to the ASP.NET Controls approach. Instead of using pure html, it is easier to use the TextBox wrappers provided by ASP.NET:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="value"></asp:TextBox>
```

The rest of the code stays the same.

Comment: Your suggestion is good but "the rest of the code **does not** stay the same", he needs to change $('#value') for $('#<%=value.ClientId%>')